# angularjs ng-show binding doesn't work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="Picture in Pictures">
    <td>{{Picture.Id}}</td>
    <td>
        <div ng-hide="Picture.editorEnabled">
            {{Picture.Name}}
        </div>
        <div ng-show="Picture.editorEnabled">
            <input ng-model="Picture.editName" class="form-control" ng-show="Picture.editorEnabled">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" name="editButton" class="btn btn-warning" ng-hide="Picture.editorEnabled"
                ng-click="enableEditor(Picture)">Edit
        </button>
        <div ng-show="Picture.editorEnabled">
            <button type="button" name="saveEditButton" class="btn btn-success"
                    ng-click="saveEditor(editName,editImageUrl,Picture)">Save
            </button>
            <button type="button" name="cancelEditButton" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="disableEditor(Picture)">
                Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and here is my controller code:

```
$scope.enableEditor = function(picture) {
    picture.editorEnabled = true;
    picture.editName      = picture.Name;
    picture.editImageUrl  = picture.ImageUrl;
};

$scope.disableEditor = function(picture) {
    picture.editorEnabled = false;
    picture.editName      = null;
    picture.editImageUrl  = null;
};

$scope.saveEditor = function(name, url, picture) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/pictures/edit/' + picture.Id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            ImageUrl: url,
            Name: name
        },
        success: function() {
            picture.Name     = picture.editName;
            picture.ImageUrl = picture.editImageUrl;
            $scope.disableEditor(picture);
        }
    });
};
```

when I click 'Edit' appears editing fields and Save,Cancel buttons.
when I click 'Cancel' it dissapears.
when I click 'Save' fields saves to DB, method `disableEditor` executes on same object, I checked `Id` property, and in debugger it showes that `editorEnabled` is false, but in my browser still exist Save,Cancel buttons and fields for editing. I click again on 'Save' and it dissapears.

Comment: because you are using `$.ajax` which requires using `$apply` to tell angular to update view. Use `$http` and issue will be gone because it manages $apply internally

Comment: thank you, sorry for simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using `$http` instead of `$.ajax`. jQuery's `$.ajax` executes outside of Angular's scope. Any code in a callback would not be reflected on your scope because this occurs outside of Angular's digest cycle. Try the following instead:

```
var url = 'admin/pictures/edit/' + picture.Id;

var data = $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
    ImageUrl: url,
    Name: name
});

var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
};

$http.post(url, data, config).then(function() {
    picture.Name     = picture.editName;
    picture.ImageUrl = picture.editImageUrl;
    $scope.disableEditor(picture);
});
```

For this to work, you'll need to inject the `$http` and `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` services into your controller. I'm assuming you need to submit this as form, since that's how `$.ajax` works by default. This requires Angular 1.4+.

Note, while it is possible to use `$.ajax` and then wrap your success code in a `$timeout` or `$scope.$apply()`, you're better off using Angular's own `$http`.

Comment: More complete answer than mine. Also good to mention that it is still possible using jQuery, but not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because everything that you do in `$scope.saveEditor` happens outside of angular (I assume `$` is jQuery). This is simply not the angular way.

You should have a deeper look into https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http the angular HTTP service, and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $apply every time you use something that is not "angular way", like Anid has already mentioned.

For example if you use jQuery's http instead of angular's $http, you will have to add $scope.$apply.